# iTextSharp 5.5.13.1 no data is available for encoding 10000 when extracting text from PDF

Tags: c#, itext, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to extract text from a multipage PDF document and almost all documents extract fine, but a couple of documents blow up with the encoding 10000 error.  The only unique thing about the document pages that don't work is that they have a button and form fields on them.

```
            {
                var pageNumbersToSave = new List<int>();
                for (var i = 1; i <= r.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var s       = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage( r, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy() );
```

I also tried using a PDFStamper to flatten the form elements but that didn't change anything:

```
            byte[] flatBytes;
            using ( var r = new PdfReader( pdfBytes ) )
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var flattener = new PdfStamper(r, ms))
                    {
                        for ( var i = 1; i <= r.NumberOfPages; i++ )
                        {
                            r.AcroFields.RemoveFieldsFromPage( i );
                        }
                        flattener.FormFlattening = true;
                        flattener.Close();
                    }
                    flatBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
```

Obviously in the top code if I was testing with the stamper I was using flatBytes and not pdfBytes.

Full exception message:
No data is available for encoding 10000. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

```
Stack Trace:
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32 codepage)
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32 codepage, EncoderFallback encoderFallback, DecoderFallback decoderFallback)
   at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.IanaEncodings.GetEncodingEncoding(String name)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncodings.ConvertToString(Byte[] bytes, String encoding)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont.FillEncoding(PdfName encoding)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont.DoType1TT()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont.Init()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.DocumentFont..ctor(PRIndirectReference refFont)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont..ctor(PRIndirectReference refFont)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.GetFont(PRIndirectReference ind)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.SetTextFont.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.FormXObjectDoHandler.HandleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfStream stream, PdfIndirectReference refi, ICollection markedContentInfoStack)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.DisplayXObject(PdfName xobjectName)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.Do.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener, IDictionary`2 additionalContentOperators)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
   at VerataParsers.ECWPdfExtractor.StripImagesFromPdf(Byte[] pdfBytes, Int32& adjustedPageCount) in C:\Users\Dell T5610\source\repos\SecureDirectMessaging\VerataParsers\ECWPdfExtractor.cs:line 85
```

Comment: *"but a couple of documents blow up with the encoding 10000 error"* - what does that mean? Furthermore, if the issue only occurs for very special pdfs, we obviously need an example pdf to analyze the issue...

Comment: It means that out of 3000 pages or so, 2 pages throw that exception.  I can't upload examples due to HIPAA.  I'm 99% sure its due to the form elements on the offending pages since that was the commonality on the bad pages and everything else worked fine.

Comment: Chances are we cannot seriously help without an example. But you could start by properly quoting the exception and its stack trace, probably based on that information one can give you some direction to investigate further.

Comment: Exception message and stack trace added.  Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Ok. So on the page on which the issue occurs there is a XObject with a font with a troublesome encoding value. It is *not* an active form field but it *may be* a flattened form field. When inspecting the document with RUPS or a similar tool, therefore, check those font encoding entries.

Answer (score 9):

Fixed by adding the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages NuGet package and then registering it as follows:

```
            var codePages = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(codePages);
```