# iText 7.1.14 'SymbolEncoding' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: powershell, itext7

I'm reading some Chase bank statements with iText7 in PowerShell, using the following code,

```
$path = .\blabla.pdf
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\dll\itext.kernel.dll" #dll loads nicely.
$pdfDoc  = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new([iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new($path))
$text = for ($a = 1; $a -le $pdfdoc.GetNumberOfPages(); $a++) {
    [iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdfDoc.GetPage($a))
}
```

most statements get read nicely by iText7, but from some statements I get the following error thrown

```
ErrorRecord                 : Exception calling "GetTextFromPage" with "1" argument(s): "'SymbolEncoding' is not a supported encoding name. For       
                              information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
                              Parameter name: name"
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : Exception calling "GetTextFromPage" with "1" argument(s): "'SymbolEncoding' is not a supported encoding name. For       
                              information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
                              Parameter name: name"
Data                        : {System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo}
InnerException              : System.ArgumentException: 'SymbolEncoding' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom       
                              encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
                              Parameter name: name
                                 at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
                                 at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
                                 at iText.IO.Util.IanaEncodings.GetEncodingEncoding(String name)
                                 at iText.IO.Util.EncodingUtil.ConvertToBytes(Char[] chars, String encoding)
                                 at iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.ConvertToBytes(String text, String encoding)
                                 at iText.IO.Font.FontEncoding.FillNamedEncoding()
                                 at iText.IO.Font.FontEncoding.CreateFontEncoding(String baseEncoding)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Font.PdfType1Font..ctor(PdfDictionary fontDictionary)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(PdfDictionary fontDictionary)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.GetFont(PdfDictionary fontDict)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.SetTextFontOperator.Invoke(PdfCanvasProcessor processor,        
                              PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfResources resources)
                                 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy,   
                              IDictionary`2 additionalContentOperators)
                                 at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
TargetSite                  : Void ConvertToMethodInvocationException(System.Exception, System.Type, System.String, Int32,
                              System.Reflection.MemberInfo)
StackTrace                  :    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception exception, Type    
                              typeToThrow, String methodName, Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo memberInfo)
                                 at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
HelpLink                    :
Source                      : System.Management.Automation
HResult                     : -2146233087
```

I'm at total loss. I'm no programmer and cannot for the life of mine figure out how to resolve this. I couldn't even find almost any iText related posts with this error ([One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227368/itextsharp-5-5-13-1-no-data-is-available-for-encoding-10000-when-extracting-text)). Is there anything I can do in PowerShell to resolve this?

I wish I would be able to to provide a PDF that can reproduce this error, but I encountered this error on  Chase bank statements so... yeah. For reference I got he error on bank statements from (07,2015 - 10,2016 and some 2018's).

Comment: Seems that indeed that question is the same as mine. Thanks for pointing that out.
Would you be able to point me to where I can get more high level info how to utilize "Encoding.RegisterProvider" ? Is that a iText class?

Comment: Sorry, I have no expertise in this problem domain.